# wheni press button to change background color the color will be saved in local store, so do the other button

Tags: javascript, html

I have done that the background color will be changed when pressing it fron original color to another, but is not getting saved when i pressed the button! How can i do that when pressing it goes to local storage ? lang is finnish

Here is the code: surley i have not defined the varaible becaue i dont know how i would ?

```
function haeArvo(){
        //Tässä haetaan localStorage
        document.body.classList.add("bodybgGradient");
    }
         function myFunction() {
        document.body.classList.remove("bodybgBlue");
        document.body.classList.add("bodybgGradient");
        console.log('toimi');
        // laita local storageen talteen muuttuja 
    }

    function myFunction2() {
        document.body.classList.remove("bodybgGradient");
        document.body.classList.add("bodybgBlue");
    }

    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
                // Store
                localStorage.setItem("chosen color", color);
    </script>
    
</head>
<body onload="haeArvo()" >
```

Buttons code :

```
<div>
            <label>Vaihda tausta väriä:</label>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Gradient</button>
            <button onclick="myFunction2()">Blue</button>

        </div>
```

Comment: Please follow [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert your localStorage logica inside a function. So you can call that function inside the event listeners(myFunction, myFunction2) you've created. You can pass the color as a parameter to store the correct color inside the localStorage.
Is this what you're looking for?

```js
function haeArvo() {
    //Tässä haetaan localStorage
    document.body.classList.add("bodybgGradient");
}

function myFunction() {
    document.body.classList.remove("bodybgBlue");
    document.body.classList.add("bodybgGradient");
    console.log('toimi');
    saveToLocalStorage("bgGradient") // pass your color as a parameter
    // laita local storageen talteen muuttuja 
}

function myFunction2() {
    document.body.classList.remove("bodybgGradient");
    document.body.classList.add("bodybgBlue");
    saveToLocalStorage("blue") // pass your color as a parameter
}

function saveToLocalStorage(color) {
    if (typeOf(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem("chosenColor", color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnks, thats what i have been looking for.